# PostgreSQL - Query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am trying to create a stored procedure in postgresql which will return multiple rows from a table/result set from a join between multiple tables. When I am trying to execute the procedure I am getting an error 'Query has no destination for result data'. I am simplifying my procedure with the below example. postgresql version --> 14.X

```
create or replace procedure sample()
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
select col1,col2,col3,col4 from tablename;
end;
$$

--call sample()
```

Comment: U can use function which behaves as stored procedure

Comment: Already asked [hundreds of times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+"Query+has+no+destination+for+result+data")